# Como usar uma variável do $scope dentro do ng-class

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```html
<a ng-class="{'text-{{color}}-6': menu == '#background'}" href="#background">
   My Menu
</a:
```

Funciona, a princípio ele adiciona a classe text-red-6 ao elemento. Porém quando eu altero o color do `$scope`, o `ng-class` não altera a classe.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui utilizando operador ternário em no atributo class :

```
class="{{menu == '#background' ? 'text-' + color + '-6' : ''}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
<div ng-class="{'{{class}}': menu == '#background'}">
```

...

```
$scope.color = 'red';
$scope.class = 'text-' + color + '-6';
```